# ubuntu ram is displayed incorrectly in about computer

Tags: ubuntu, memory, performance

I have ubuntu running on my machine, and the "about this computer" window says I have only 3.3GiB on it. I previously had only a 4 GB chip and recently added an 8GB chip too. In terminal, it shows both the chips. Please respond fast as I need to execute a memory exhaustive program.

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit OS?

Comment: 64 bit OS ubuntu

Comment: It is not uncommon for laptops (or anything using integrated graphics) to have some RAM (several hundreds MB) set aside for the integrated graphics. So that would explain 3.3 vs 4. That doesn't explain 3.3 vs 8. What does your BIOS say?

Comment: The BIOS also says that i have 12 GB of RAM